# Tensorflow 2.0 custom gradient function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I am trying to build a custom gradient for A piece-wise continuous function that I found in the paper

A continuum among logarithmic, linear, and exponential functions, and its potential to improve generalization in neural networks - Godfrey

Current problem: the gradient explodes for the learnable parameter in a custom layer of my network, causing `nans` to be generated. This custom layer is a learnable activation function defined in the paper above.

Tried solutions

- clip the gradient the optimizer -> This had no affect when I compiled the model with e.g `keras.optimizer.Adam(clipnorm=0.5)`
- clip the value of the learnable parameter in the custom layer -> This gave some errors that I am unable to recall
- create a custom gradient calculation to control the gradients of the learnable parameter -> not sure how the gradient should be calculated.

My current gradient calculation function is like this

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def call_lt0(alpha_actv, x):
    def grad(dx):
        grad_x = 1/(1-alpha_actv * (alpha_actv + x))
        grad_alpha = (tf.math.log(1-alpha_actv * (alpha_actv + x)) - ((2 * alpha_actv ** 2 + alpha_actv * x)/(alpha_actv ** 2 + alpha_actv * x - 1))) / alpha_actv ** 2
        return grad_x * dx, grad_alpha * dx  # denk ik..?
    return (tf.math.exp(alpha_actv * x) - 1) / alpha_actv + alpha_actv, grad
```

where I give the gradient of x variable and the learnable parameter alpha. However, when I check these outputs with `tf.GradientTape` I get only one output.. where I expected two, because of my definition of `grad`.
Also, when I let keras/tensorflow calculate everything, and check the output with `tf.GradientTape` again, I get only one value.. which is what I would expect for the single learnable parameter.
SO somewhere I am doing something wrong, or misinterpreting the `grad` function.

Can someone point me the way?

Comment: Please provide code samples of the model and the training.

Comment: @thushv89 I woud like to, but that might bloat my post a bit.. I believe my error might reside in the definition or interpretation of my custom gradient. For example.. I want to learn the `alpha_actv` parameter, but to do so I need the value for `x` as well. In this definition, I also need to provide the gradient for `x` but that one does not need any updating.. So am I doing something wrong in that?

Comment: What does your model look like? Fully connected?